# Django: Decimal Field Initial Value

Tags: django, foreign-keys, form-fields

I am working on an UpdateView of a form. I am having hard time displaying the initial value of grades per subject. I can display the subjects fine in the template, however I can't display the grades using the DecimalField. If change DecimalField to ModelChoiceField in forms.py, I can view the grades in a drop down menu in template but this is not what I want. I want the user to be able to edit using DecimalField.

forms.py

```
class GradeUpdateForm(CrispyFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):
s_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.none(), empty_label=None)
final_grade = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style':'width:80px'}), decimal_places=2, max_digits=5,)
class Meta:
    model = SGrade
    fields = [
        's_name',
        'final_grade',
    ]
```

views.py

```
class SchoolDashboardGradesUpdateView(SchoolStudentMixin, UpdateView):
template_name = 'education/dashboard/grades_update.html'
model = SubjectGrade
form_class = GradeUpdateForm

# def get_object(self):
#     return get_object_or_404(Recipient, pk=self.kwargs['pk']) 

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['subject_name'].queryset = Subject.objects.filter(
                                                                sgrade__recipient__id=self.kwargs.get('pk'),
                                                                sgrade__status='approved').values_list('name', flat=True)
    form.fields['final_grade'].queryset = SGrade.objects.filter(
                                                                    recipient__id=self.kwargs.get('pk'),
                                                                    status='approved').values_list('final_grade', flat=True)
student = Student.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')
for x in student.sgrade_set.all():
 if x.status == 'approved':
  forms.fields['final_grade'].initial = x.final_grade
```

template

```
<tbody>
      {% for instance in form.subject_name.field.choices %}
        <tr>
         <td>{{instance.1}}</td>
         <td>{{form.final_grade}}</td>
        </tr>

      {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this? I am a complete beginner.

Comment: You can't set a queryset for final_grade as it is a DecimalField. That's why it works for ModelChoiceField and not for DecimalField. You can only set one value for DecimalField. [Docs for DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Then I should loop through the final grade and append it to the DecimalField however decimal field doesn't have that. I can only set form.fields['final_grade'].initial = final_grade but this will only put the initial value of 1 final grade to all subjects (e.g. Final grade = 88, all subjects will have 88 as inittial value )

Comment: I updated the post. Tried playing around with a for loop to get the final grades however, it only gets the last value of the final grade in the loop and set it as the initial value.

Comment: Yes, that will happen, because in each iteration you are assigning a different value to initial and overwriting the previous value, so it will retain the last value.

Comment: You can't basically put multiple initial grades in one decimal field. A decimal field is for one grade (one decimal), and intuitively that should make sense. If you want to have multiple initial grades and edit the grades on a per-subject basis, then what you should do is have a form where you have a DecimalField for each subject's grade, like 'English: <DecimalField>, Maths: <DecimalField> etc.', and assign separate initial values to each of those DecimalFields. And then you can have the user edit each of those separately and submit it together.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. How about if I manually create forms in template and in the name="", i will call the name of the fields generated by forms(e.g. auto generated name by decimal field is final_grade). Do you think the information will be caught if I submit?